# just_audio_background continues playing after closing app

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I identified that just_audio_background continues to play the audio even after closing the app and closing the widget that appears when dragging it down (Android).
The audio only stops playing if I go to app information and click force close.

Is this behavior expected? I would like just_audio_background to only play if the app is in the background. That is, if you close the app, it should stop playing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose of your player controller under the dispose function like this.
use your controller name instead of "_player". try this .

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
     player.dispose();
     super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: That's works for iPhones and most Android devices, but not work for example for some of Samsung devices. Seems like dispose just not called in this case. And app still work in background mode.